# How to use emsdk/emscripten to build c++ and reference/include gmp?

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten, emsdk

wasm-ld error: unknown file type: libgmp.a
wasm-ld:error: undefined symbol: __gmpz_clear

I want to build https://github.com/Iwctwbh/Factorial-BenchMark in wasm.
Can you tell me the correct steps?

wasm-ld error: unknown file type: libgmp.a
wasm-ld:error: undefined symbol: __gmpz_clear

I want to build https://github.com/Iwctwbh/Factorial-BenchMark in wasm.
Can you tell me the correct steps?

Below are my steps

## GMP

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

Then, I get .lib/libgmp.a

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

int main() {
    mpz_class result = 1;
    int n = 10;
    std::cout << "Fibonacci(" << n << ") = " << fibonacci(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(FibonacciProject)

# Enable Emscripten
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE D:\\emsdk\\emsdk\\upstream\\emscripten\\cmake\\Modules\\Platform\\Emscripten.cmake)

# Set the output format to WebAssembly (wasm)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".html")

# Add the source file to the project
add_executable(FibonacciProject main.cpp)

add_library(gmp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(gmp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION D://gmp//.libs//libgmp.a)
target_include_directories(FibonacciProject PRIVATE D:\\gmp)
target_link_libraries(FibonacciProject gmp)
```

Then, I try
emcmake cmake ..
emmake make

I tried it in Windows11/Linux/Docker, but it always gives an error and is not the same.
Please help me.